# My bootstrap dropdown menu is not working in navigation bar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

```
<!-- navbar-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-header navbar-brand">MYSITE</a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Tags <span class="caret"></span></a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">menu2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">menu3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">menu4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">menu5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">menu6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">menu7</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">menu8</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">menu9</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">menu10</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">menu11</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">menu12</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">menu13</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">menu14</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">menu15</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">menu16</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">menu17</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">menu18</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">menu19</a></li>
            </ul>

        </li>   

        </ul> 
    </div>

</nav>
```

I am learning bootstrap and i am trying to create a layout through the same. My dropdown menu is not working and am not able to detect the fault. Please help!

Comment: What's the problem ? It seems just fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9do8qhcf/)

Comment: when i click "tags" then it does nothing. No division or menu pops up saying menu1, menu2 and so on.

Comment: Check my example, I've the same html structure as you. Do you have any error in your console ? Don't forget to include Jquery.

Comment: No, there is no error in the browser it is totally ideal. Bootstrap's dropdown tutorial at w3schools does not mention any jquery that is to be inserted to create a dropdown?

Comment: Bootstrap does need Jquery actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its working fine, You need to add `jquery`, `Bootstrap ja`, Bootstrap CSS` then if will work

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <!-- navbar-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-header navbar-brand">MYSITE</a>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Tags <span class="caret"></span></a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menu2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menu3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menu4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menu5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menu6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menu7</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menu8</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menu9</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menu10</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menu11</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menu12</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menu13</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menu14</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menu15</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menu16</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menu17</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menu18</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menu19</a></li>
                </ul>

            </li>   

            </ul> 
        </div>

    </nav>
```

Comment: see i have included all the style sheets and jquery here: http://pastebin.com/4uQLQFyx

but it won't make any difference. :(

Comment: Let me check:-)

Comment: Can you try with the latest version of jquery `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js`

Comment: now my browser console has this error : GET https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.j%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bs 403 ()

Comment: i think it's forbidden?

Comment: not found :o
 GET https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.m%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bin.js 404 ()

Comment: wee can refer `jQuery` website leave `cloudflare` `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js`

Comment: it seems that my browser is not able to load any jquery script. I think i should update my browser. :/
Thank you sir for interacting :)

Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
    at bootstrap.min.js:6